# Serial send in python

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm trying to send a string and a variable trough serial port in python.
I thought of the following command, but no success:

```
ser.write("My string variable /r/n", varible)
```

How do I send a variable in the following format?

Comment: You can use [PySerial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PySerial).

Comment: I'm using Raspberry pi as host to a chip. I'm not sure I can install this package. Is there any way python can do this?